# fill-column-indicator mode doesn't show a straight vertical line

Tags: init-file, fill-column

[image: configuration code in .emacs file]

OS windows7 64bit | GNU emacs 24.3.1

Comment: Perhaps that is by design? That it shows the fill-column on lines that are shorter, but places the marker after any line that is longer?

Comment: For me, it doesn't show the indicator for longer lines.

Comment: Is there a tab character in that line?